# Marketing Cloud - Journey splitted according to email opening

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, split

how is it possible to split the journey into two branches, according to the email opening?

This is the desired steps:

Send email --> Check if the email was opened --> if yes, continue in the journey --> if no, re-send the email.

The documentation is no helpful in this case
Thanks,
Tommaso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create an engagement split for this .

Check the screenshots below

[image]

Drag the engagement split and configure

[image]

Note that you need to configure first email and then use engagement split for your action